# How to find out how much I should read from a socket?

Tags: silverlight, sockets, network-programming

In .NET there is the DataAvailable property in the network stream and the Available property in the tcp client.
However silverlight lacks those. 
Should I send a header with the lenght of the message? I'd rather not waste network resources.
Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are micro-optimizing. Why do you think that another 4 bytes would affect the performance?

In other words: Use a length header.

### Update

I saw your comment on the other answer. You are using `BeginRead` in the wrong way. It will never block or wait until the entire buffer have been filled.

You should declare a buffer which can receive your entire message. The return value from `EndRead` will report the number of bytes received.

You should also know that TCP is stream based. There is ***no*** guarantees that your entire JSON message will be received at once (or that only your first message is received). Therefore you must have some sort of way to know when a message is complete.

And I say it again: A length header will hardly affect the performance.

Comment: In my case, they might. I might delay other network events that are much more important.

Comment: The TCP header is between 20 and 60 bytes. And you got the Nagle Algorithm that delays your packets. I seriously doubt that 4 bytes will affect performance. If you have smaller packets, use a `byte`, or a `Int16` to reduce the number of bytes then.

Comment: @jgauffin: Well, I'm working with IP over high voltage. I need to use as less bandwidth as possible.

Comment: How large is an average message? And what do the messages contain?

Comment: @jgauffin: JSON-RPC messages that may or may not contain binary data of arbitrary size. But I'd rather reduce the noise as much as possible. IP over high voltage, in certain implementations is half duplex.

Comment: @jgauffin: So it won't wait until the buffer is filled? Why is that?

Comment: Because TCP is stream based. You never know the number of bytes that you'll receive in a read.

Comment: @jgauffin: So why do the DataAvailable and Available exists than?

Comment: What I mean is that just because you send 15 bytes doesn't mean that you'll receive 15 bytes. It depends on what the socket implementation does with your send request. `DataAvailable` isn't really useful when working with `BeginRead` since it's an asynchronous operation.

Comment: @jgauffin: Sure it does. This is TCP. UDP doesn't guarantee that all data will be received.

Comment: You might have to call `BeginReceive` twice to get all 15 bytes. TCP only guarantees that everything will be received and in the correct order. Not that everything will be received with the same number of calls to `Receive` as the number of calls to `Send`.

Comment: @jgauffin: Why isn't there a BeginReceive until the buffer is full then?

Comment: because you are using it incorrectly. Call it as soon as the socket is connected and call `EndReceive` in the callback. Or switch to non-blocking sockets and `Receive`. Do not mix.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'waste network resources'? Every network read API I am aware of returns the actual number of bytes read, somehow. What's the actual problem here?

Comment: Silverlight is non-blocking. And I would like to check if I should read and how much to read before I read anything.

Comment: @the_drow it doesn't make any difference whether it is blocking or non-blocking. The read API will *tell* you how much it read.

Comment: @EJP: True, but the call will still occupy the socket which is somewhat wasteful.

Comment: @the_drow that is completely meaningless. Wasteful how? Non-blocking is non-blocking. Period. If you want to know whether to read the non-blocking socket at all, that's what select() is for.

Comment: @EJP: Why would you use DataAvailable and Available then? I am using it like this: `if (stream.Available) { byte[] buffer = new byte[tcpClient.Available]; stream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, callback, null);}`

Comment: @the_drow I don't. I just select or block until something arrives.